# VBA Regular Expression not working as intended

Tags: regex, vba

Alright, I've been trying to figure this one out but being pretty new to Regular Expressions, I've been less than successful.  What my objective is here is to produce a match comparing one string against another that may be much larger or the same size as the former string.  This match should only occur if the first string 1. is a case insensitive match to some part of the other string, 2. the string successfully matched within the other should be a separate word or phrase, not a part of another word, which means it is lead by either the start of the string or a space and ended by the end of a string or a space.  Any help from a skilled Regular Expression user would be most welcome.

```
'this yields : run time error 5018 = Unexpected quantifier in regular expression
RegExPattern = "(\b|^)?" + "[" + ColumnArr(PhraseCt) + "]" + "(\b|[ ])?)" 
With RegEx
     .MultiLine = False
     .Global = True
     .IgnoreCase = False
     .Pattern = RegExPattern
End With
Set Matches = RegEx.Execute(SearchTerm)
```

Comment: If it's case insensitive, shouldn't it be .IgnoreCase = True?

Comment: Also, I think you've got an extra ) at the end of your regex

Comment: The parentheses in your example are unmatched. You have 2 open and 3 closed parens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\b` should match the beginning of a string (see [VBA Excel regex - \b word boundary doesn't match if word is at beginning of string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11867580/vba-exel-regex-b-word-boundary-doesnt-match-if-word-is-at-beginning-of-strin) for confirmation of that in Excel 2010). So you should be able to just use

```
RegExPattern = "\b" + ColumnArr(PhraseCt) + "\b"
```

(assuming that `ColumnArr(PhraseCt)` is the word you are searching for). And also use `IgnoreCase = True` if you want it to be case-insensitive.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments.  It's amazing how two simple mistakes can make you look like a n00b.  I wish I could upvote you guys more!

Comment: `I wish I could upvote you guys more!` @user1902208: I have done that for you ;)

Comment: I'd recommend using & for string concatenation also--otherwise you can get things like "2" + 2  is "4", but "2" + "2" is "22",  "2" & 2 is "22"

Comment: @DanMetheus Good point -- I spend most of my time in C# & so didn't notice that.